# What is the similar method of onDestroy() or applicationWillTerminate() in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I am new in Flutter. I am working on one of my demo Flutter app. I have created 3 screens (Login, Signup and Home) in my app. I am just navigating to the Home screen from the login screen. Now I want to check - Is my app is alive or closed? - by clearing the app from the recent apps in Android and IOS. I have checked *AppLifecycleState.detached* and also checked override method *dispose()* but these are not calling while user killed the app. Please help me how I come to know that my app got killed. Which method I need to use.

I have used *AppLifecycleState.paused* for other process. So I want any other way to handle it.

In native Android we can check this with the help of *onDestroy()* method and in iOS native app we can check it with the help of *applicationWillTerminate()* .

Which method I need to use for Flutter?

Comment: Try AppLifecycleState.suspending.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @vishnuanilkumar . I checked this one but this is not working too :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution to detect if the app destroyed. In flutter we have one method name - *dispose()* In my case the *dispose()* method was not getting called on app destroy. So I just updated my *dispose()* method and added - **@mustCallSuper** **@protected** See the below code.

```
 @mustCallSuper
  @protected
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);

    print('dispose called.............');
    super.dispose();
  }
```